Barplot bars disappear with zooming (ggplot2)
I'm graphing a large number of bars in a barplot (>1000), and want to color a subset of them black to highlight them. However, with this large number I run into what I think is an issue with screen resolution. When I zoom in some black bars appear or disappear (notice the rug plot without corresponding black bars above it), and white bars appear (which should not be there).
My priority is the black bars. Does anyone have advice to ensure all of the black bars appear? The rug plot at the bottom has the same issue where the rug dashes with disappear and reappear depending on whether I zoom in or out. I've tried overlaying points on top, which works but the aesthetic is pretty terrible and much less intuitive.
Thank you!
Shawn.
Image of barplot
# Load library and create dummy data
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1020)

a <- data.frame(graph = seq(2000),order=rep(seq(1000),2),facet=c(rep('one',1000),rep('two',1000)),col=sample(2000) %% 100 == 0)

# Create plot with facets
testPlot1 <- ggplot(a, aes(x = order, y = graph)) + geom_bar(aes(fill=col),stat = "identity",na.rm=T) +
  theme_classic() + ggtitle('Plot A with facets') +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c(`FALSE`='lightgrey',`TRUE`='black')) +
  geom_rug(sides='b',aes(color=col)) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c(`FALSE`='white',`TRUE`='black')) + guides(color='none',x='none') +
  facet_wrap(~facet,scales='free_x')
print(testPlot1)

# Session Info
sessionInfo()

# R version 4.4.0 (2024-04-24)
# Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
# Running under: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
# 
# Matrix products: default
# BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/libblas.so.3 
# LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/libopenblasp-r0.3.26.so;  LAPACK version 3.12.0
# 
# locale:
#   [1] LC_CTYPE=C.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C           LC_TIME=C.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=C.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=C.UTF-8   
# [6] LC_MESSAGES=C.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=C.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C              LC_ADDRESS=C           LC_TELEPHONE=C        
# [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=C.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C   
# 
# time zone: Etc/UTC
# tzcode source: system (glibc)
# 
# attached base packages:
#   [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
# 
# other attached packages:
#   [1] dplyr_1.1.4   ggplot2_3.5.1
# 
# loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#   [1] labeling_0.4.3    utf8_1.2.4        R6_2.5.1          tidyselect_1.2.1  farver_2.1.2      magrittr_2.0.3   
# [7] gtable_0.3.5      glue_1.7.0        tibble_3.2.1      pkgconfig_2.0.3   generics_0.1.3    lifecycle_1.0.4  
# [13] cli_3.6.2         fansi_1.0.6       scales_1.3.0      grid_4.4.0        vctrs_0.6.5       withr_3.0.0      
# [19] compiler_4.4.0    rstudioapi_0.16.0 tools_4.4.0       munsell_0.5.1     pillar_1.9.0      colorspace_2.1-0 
# [25] rlang_1.1.4      



I'm not sure what the rug plot is supposed to be doing here.  Rug plots display the marginal distribution of a multi-dimensional response.  But a bar plot summarises a univariate response.  However, I agree that this is almost certainly a resolution issue: you're trying to plot 2000 bars alongside each other, and allow space for axes, margins, legends, etc.  That's going to take a lot of real estate...

Save it as an image with a very high resolution, is about your only option if this is what your plot needs to be.

You're trying to plot 2000 bars, and the bars are taking up about 2/3 of the plot width, so you'd probably want at least 3000 pixels to have it big enough for 1 pixel per bar, which is more than my macbook pro has. You may want to think about aggregating your data, perhaps you could use geom_area for all the gray, and maybe even geom_segment for the black.

The example above is random data, but what I'd be looking for is a buildup of black bars on the left or right hand side of the plot. My priority is seeing where the black bars are located, the rug plot is a workaround but it still has the resolution issue. I've been generating these as PDFs since I'll generate dozens to hundreds of plots at a time for review.

Draw the black bars over top of the grey ones:
ggplot(data = NULL, aes(x = order, y = graph)) + 
  geom_bar(data = a %>%  filter( col == FALSE), colour = "lightgrey",stat = "identity",na.rm=T) +
  geom_bar(data = a %>%  filter( col == TRUE), colour = "black",stat = "identity",na.rm=T)

